# Qt C++ Взятие числа из textBox и дальнейшее его использование в SQL запросе

Tags: sql, qt, qtcreator

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JABLl.png)

Необходимо взять значение textBox как переменную и вставить ее значение в sql запрос с дальнейшим выводом в tableView.

может я его не туда куда то вставляю? на данный момент он выводит запрос но без данных, другие функции где есть запросы работают без проблем. Есть у comboBox такой слот как Activated нужен ли он вообще?

есть код который по идеи должен [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
QString filter = QString("tour.lenght_of_stay='%1'")
.arg(ui->comboBox2->currentText());
QSqlQueryModel *setquery1 = new QSqlQueryModel;
setquery1->setQuery("select * from tour where 
tour.lenght_of_stay>"+filter+"");
QTableView *tv = new QTableView(this);
tv->setModel(setquery1);
ui->tableView->setModel(setquery1);
```

Comment: Проверьте еще раз корректность составления запроса. 
`select * from tour where tour.lenght_of_stay > tour.lenght_of_stay = '%1'`

Comment: не работает но в ошибках есть 
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_comboBoxCountry_activated(QString)
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_comboBoxCountry_activated(int)

Comment: это значит вы задали слоты, но потом удалили их реализацию. удалите из .h on_comboBoxCountry_activated.